# how do i open a new page with express routing?

Tags: javascript, post

How do you redirect the page back to `index.html` after the user submits changes to the database. 
Below is the post `script` that im using to update the database with the users inputs, but after the user submits the changes, the page stays on `/user_create`

```js
router.post('/user_create', (req, res) => {
    const path = require('path');
    const id = req.body.create_id_number;
    const firstName = req.body.create_first_name;
    const lastName = req.body.create_last_name;
    const projectName = req.body.create_project_name;
    const location = req.body.create_location;
    const department = req.body.create_department_name;
    const queryString = 'INSERT INTO testTable (idtestTable, someInfo, otherInfo, lastName, firstName, department) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

    pool.query(queryString, [id, projectName, location, lastName, firstName, department], (err, results, fields) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('Failed to inser new user: ', err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Inserted a new user with id: ' + id);
      res.end();
    });
});
```

Right before `res.end()` i tried `res.sendFile(path)` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: If you want to change the browser url when backend "finish" the job, you can send a header "Location" with the url to be redirected, after that, browser will perform the redirection and the backend can continue with the job on background

Comment: res.redirect(url) right before res.end() seems to work